# Cross site authentication

Tags: authentication

I'm just wondering how cross-site authentication is handled for completely external companies?
e.g. My site acts a "portal" onto another completely external site.

Is there a standard way of doing this so the user is not prompted to log in again?

I know with e.g. eBay-> PayPal you have to re-authenticate, but is this the only/most sensible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to depend on what that other site uses as an authentication method.

Look at [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) (which in essence a way of saying to the other site that they can trust your assertion that this user is who you say he is). [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) is another system doing much the same thing.

In general, this is [federated identity management,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity)

Comment: Thanks for this (and to you Spencer). I didn't think this was a simple task :(
Think for sites we DO have influence over we'll look at SAML or an independant application as below.  Otherwise, we're limited!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this is to create a third application which is responsible for authentication and permissions. I've written a blog entry about one such application I've created for my own pet projects.

http://www.netortech.com/Blog/Entry/12/Web-passport-services

Comment: Your article was helpful to me, but the diagram you mentioned is not listed.